# zend php multiple array json_encoding

Tags: php, javascript, json, zend-framework

I have a problem with the json functionality in zend and js.

I try to encode a single array containing some number of models like this:

```
echo json_encode(Application_Model_Marker::getMarkers());

var mark = JSON.parse(jsonVal); //in js
```

where getMarkers is a static method that returns an array of marker models.

This works fine and when I parse it in the js script and try accessing the values of the json object it works fine.

If however I try to create and send an array of array like this:

```
$allData = array();
$allData['info'] = Application_Model_Marker::getMarkers();
$allData['openingHours'] = Application_Model_Openinghours::getOpeningHours();
$allData['happyHours'] = Application_Model_Happyhour::getHappyHours();

echo json_encode($allData);
```

It still sends all the correct information when I try to alert(jsonVal.responseText); in js.

It has three arrays each containg some arrays of objects.

However when I try to initialize a variable to the parsed json object like in the first example, I can't access the values and it seems some kind of error occurs as the program stops when I try it.

I don't quite get it as it has all the correct info when i just try to print the response text from the encoded json object.

Any ideas how to do this multidimensional json encoding?

Comment: Can you clarify that »some kind of error«? Most of the time errors *do* help in pinpointing the cause and simply omitting it (or saying »it doesn't work«) makes the task very hard for others to help you.

Comment: How do you receive response and initialize `jsonVal`? The 1st parameter to `JSON.parse()` should be string variable, but you mentioned `alert(jsonVal.responseText)`, so I guess `jsonVal` is an object? Then you may try `JSON.parse(jsonVal.responseText)` or `jsonVal` is already json-parsed object?

Comment: When debugging calls such as this, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) comes in handy. It allows you to debug your javascript/dom with errors and such. Secondly, have you tried accessing `mark.info`? Is it undefined?

Comment: mark.info is exactly undefined. 
I tried JSON.parse(jsonVal.responseText) which works with a single array as well but still not with several arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hopefully it'll work :

```
<sctript>
var mark;
eval("mark = "+jsonVal+";");
</sctrip>
```

Comment: I thought of trying eval but I've read that it's very bad practice compared to parse ?

Comment: if the data is yours From your server and you have full control over it, then eval isn't a bad practice .